# Would I need to use the run loop with my NSTimer in this case?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nstimer, nsrunloop

I don't want to sleep() my app, but I do want it to wait while my timer completes it's action (basically updating 4 UILabels, one per second).

There is some code that I want to fire back in the main loop, after the timer completes - I want it to wait until the timer is done. At the moment, the main loop kicks off the timer and then goes straight into the next block of code (while the timer ticks away in the background). But actually, I want the timer to complete its updating of the 4 UILabels and then I want the main program to fire the next block of code.

I'm Googling and watching several bad tutorials on YouTube but I think I should be using a run loop. Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the code you want to run INTO the function the timer calls? That way it won't get called till the timer completes?

Comment: I guess I could do that, it just didn't seem very object-oriented as there'd be a lot of code that has nothing to do with the timer.

Answer (score 0):

you require to use `NSTimer`.

**Use below Code as Reference.**

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(callAfterSixtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

After each 60.0 second , iOS will call the below function

```
-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    NSLog(@"red");
    //Put all your UILabel here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think runloop can be of any help to you, thomsan and jhaliya are right, do it like that. Even after that you want to try something with run loop then just try with secondary thread's run loop. Don't touch application's main run loop as your application may become non responsive